# SwiftUI custom toolbars are buggy with switching dark / light mode

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I am seeing an issue while switching between dark and light mode. The app doesn't properly changes the state between dark and light mode of the toolbars. I have to quit the app and start it again to see the effect. Tested this on both simulator and hardware, iOS 17.

```
import SwiftUI

@main
struct ElementApp: App {
    
    init() {
        // Customize UINavigationBar
        let navBarAppearance = UINavigationBarAppearance()
        navBarAppearance.backgroundEffect = UIBlurEffect(style: .systemUltraThinMaterial)

        // Check the current user interface style and set the alpha component for navBarAppearance
        if UITraitCollection.current.userInterfaceStyle == .dark {
            navBarAppearance.backgroundColor = UIColor.black.withAlphaComponent(1)
        } else {
            navBarAppearance.backgroundColor = UIColor.black.withAlphaComponent(0)
        }

        navBarAppearance.shadowColor = .clear
        UINavigationBar.appearance().standardAppearance = navBarAppearance
        UINavigationBar.appearance().compactAppearance = navBarAppearance
        UINavigationBar.appearance().scrollEdgeAppearance = navBarAppearance

        // Customize UITabBar
        let toolbarBackground = UIToolbarAppearance()
        toolbarBackground.backgroundEffect = UIBlurEffect(style: .systemUltraThinMaterial)

        // Check the current user interface style and set the alpha component for toolbarBackground
        if UITraitCollection.current.userInterfaceStyle == .dark {
            toolbarBackground.backgroundColor = UIColor.black.withAlphaComponent(1)
        } else {
            toolbarBackground.backgroundColor = UIColor.black.withAlphaComponent(0)
        }

        toolbarBackground.shadowColor = .clear
        UIToolbar.appearance().standardAppearance = toolbarBackground
        UIToolbar.appearance().scrollEdgeAppearance = toolbarBackground
    }


    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            ContentView()
        }
    }
}
```

I also tried observing the changes in the environment's color scheme within my views:

```
import SwiftUI
import UIKit

struct InterfaceStyleObserver: UIViewControllerRepresentable {
    func makeUIViewController(context: Context) -> UIViewController {
        InterfaceStyleObserverViewController()
    }

    func updateUIViewController(_ uiViewController: UIViewController, context: Context) {}

    class InterfaceStyleObserverViewController: UIViewController {
        override func traitCollectionDidChange(_ previousTraitCollection: UITraitCollection?) {
            super.traitCollectionDidChange(previousTraitCollection)
            if self.traitCollection.hasDifferentColorAppearance(comparedTo: previousTraitCollection) {
                // Update the global appearance
                ElementApp.updateAppearance()
            }
        }
    }
}

@main
struct ElementApp: App {
    init() {
        ElementApp.updateAppearance()
    }

    static func updateAppearance() {
        let isDarkMode = UITraitCollection.current.userInterfaceStyle == .dark

        // UINavigationBar appearance
        let navBarAppearance = UINavigationBarAppearance()
        navBarAppearance.backgroundEffect = UIBlurEffect(style: .systemUltraThinMaterial)
        navBarAppearance.backgroundColor = isDarkMode ? UIColor.black.withAlphaComponent(0.7) : UIColor.black.withAlphaComponent(0)
        navBarAppearance.shadowColor = .clear
        UINavigationBar.appearance().standardAppearance = navBarAppearance
        UINavigationBar.appearance().compactAppearance = navBarAppearance
        UINavigationBar.appearance().scrollEdgeAppearance = navBarAppearance

        // UIToolbar appearance
        let toolbarBackground = UIToolbarAppearance()
        toolbarBackground.backgroundEffect = UIBlurEffect(style: .systemUltraThinMaterial)
        toolbarBackground.backgroundColor = isDarkMode ? UIColor.black.withAlphaComponent(0.7) : UIColor.black.withAlphaComponent(0)
        toolbarBackground.shadowColor = .clear
        UIToolbar.appearance().standardAppearance = toolbarBackground
        UIToolbar.appearance().scrollEdgeAppearance = toolbarBackground
    }

    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            ContentView()
                .background(InterfaceStyleObserver())
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I think you can just create your own dynamic `UIColor` with [`init(dynamicProvider:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uicolor/3238041-init).